# Why does boot2docker ip fail?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am totally confused with this. I have installed boot2docker on Windows. I started it using `boot2docker start` icon. It has launched successfully. I tried out all the docker commands like `pull attach run` etc. Everything works fine. But when i try

`boot2docker ip`

It says

```
-sh : boot2docker not found.
```

What's the problem? Am i in wrong directory? or installation done wrongly? Any suggestions.

Comment: doesn't look like boot2docker is installed properly

Comment: You tried a bunch of Docker commands, not boot2docker commands. It looks like docker is running fine, but there's something weird with your boot2docker install.

Comment: @Eli What could it be?  docker@boot2docker: $ `myinput goes here`

Comment: Check the install directory. Is the bin there? If it is, is it in your PATH? Does it work when you try running the full path to the bin?

Comment: @Eli insttead of starting by clicking boot2docker start icon, i started from new cmd. I tried boot2docker download and boot2docker start. It says "Please use boot2docker ssh to SSH into the VM instead".Download is succeeded.

Comment: @Eli There is no bin. There start and delete scripts. C:/boot2docker for windows has set in PATH

Answer (score 1):

The windows version of boot2docker doesn't have a native client (unlike the MacOS version). This means that when you launch boot2docker, you're inside the Virtualbox VM. As boot2docker is installed on your host, it's not available from there. You can just open a new shell or dos prompt to run boot2docker commands (assuming your path is set up).

Comment: I don't understand the last line. Please provide an example or more info.

Comment: I mean exactly what I say. If you have cygwin installed (which you may have installed with git), open it to get a shell. If you don't have this, open a dos prompt (run->cmd if memory serves).

From there, you should be able to run things like `boot2docker ip`. If it doesn't work, you just need to update the path.